# How to read Key and value array in php when passing from Ajax Post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have an key and value array which I pass through ajax call to PHP function.
How can I read the array in PHP side using $_POST?

```
                var eImages = [{
                    ProductID: ProductID,
                    Image: image1Name, 
                    ImagePath: image1Path
                },
                {
                   ProductID: ProductID,
                   Image: image2Name, 
                   ImagePath: image2Path         
                },
                {
                   ProductID: ProductID,
                   Image: image3Name, 
                   ImagePath: image3Path
                }];

              $.ajax({
                url: "adminProcess.php/",
                method: "post",
                data:{
                    images: eImages,
                    action: 'SaveImages'
                },
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(strMessage){
                    $('#Message').text(strMessage)
                    //fnClearControls();
                }
            })
```

Comment: Well, did you take a look into what you find in `$_POST`?

Comment: Just `var_dump($_POST)` and see.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($_POST["action"] == "SaveImages") {
        yourFunctionToSave($_POST["images"]);
    }

    function yourFunctionToSave($data) {
        foreach($data as $product) {
            $ProductID = $product['ProductID'];
            $Image = $product['Image'];
            $ImagePath = $product['ImagePath'];
        }
    }
?>
```

The data is stored as a `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the product details(in the backend PHP page) in the following way,

```
foreach($_POST['images'] as $product){
    $ProductID = $product['ProductID'];
    $Image = $product['Image'];
    $ImagePath = $product['ImagePath'];
    // your code
}
```

And of course, you can simply access the `action` key of `$_POST` array using `$_POST['action']`, which in this case would give `SaveImages`. Here's the more complete example:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "SaveImages"){
    foreach($_POST['images'] as $product){
        $ProductID = $product['ProductID'];
        $Image = $product['Image'];
        $ImagePath = $product['ImagePath'];
        // your code
    }
}
```